# Unable to pass arguments from plugin form to filter hook using ajax, the data is transferring via ajax but unable to pass as arguments in filter hooks

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters

**In the end, I got error "**The Undefined array key x and y" after making the globals****

```
add_action('wp_ajax_example_ajax_request','example_ajax_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request','example_ajax_request');

function example_ajax_request() {
    if(isset($_REQUEST)) {
        $GLOBALS['x'] = $_REQUEST['fruit'];
        $GLOBALS['y'] = $_REQUEST['fruit2'];
    }
    global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "custom_currency";
        $cname =$GLOBALS['x'];
        $csymbol =$GLOBALS['y'];
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'entrytime' => current_time('timestamp'),
                'cname' => $cname,
                'symbol' => $csymbol
            ));
    echo "Currency = ".$GLOBALS['x']." Symbol = ".$GLOBALS['y'];
    die();
// ==============================================================

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );
function add_my_currency( $currency ) {

     $currency['abc'] = __( $GLOBALS['x'],'woocommerce');
     return $currency;
}
/**
 * Change a currency symbol
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'abc': $currency_symbol = $GLOBALS['y']; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Comment: Global variables are not persistent. This will set the global variables for the AJAX request, but any subsequent requests, such as navigating to another page, will not have access to any globals you defined in the AJAX request.

Comment: Not another page, in the same file, e:g index.php

Comment: The file is irrelevant. The files get reloaded every time you view another page.

Comment: how can I extend the variable scope in this case, I have to use these vars in built-in filters and action hooks

Comment: You can't. You need to save the data in the database, or as a cookie if it's user-specific.

Comment: Upon Plugin activation, DB ll be created, and data will be stored in the table, but still unable to use that data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139930/discussion-between-stranger-and-jacob-peattie).

Comment: Why are you unable to use it? Your code isn’t querying the database. That’s what it should be doing.